# How do I keep 8.E1 in excel when saving as a CSV.

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007

I enter as 8.E1 in Excel then save as a CSV it reverts to 8.00E+01, I have changed the format to TEXT as it has always worked like that in the past. We are using 2007 Excel.

Comment: For me in Excel (2016) itself, it also becomes `8.00E+01`